# Python script not working in crontab, but works fine without

Tags: python, bash, path, cron

I used in past crontab configuration file like this without problem

```
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
0 * * * * source /Users/bezoadam/Documents/FIT/6.semester/BP/bp1/bin/activate; /usr/bin/env python3 /Users/bezoadam/Documents/FIT/6.semester/BP/twitter_down.py --hashtag
0 * * * * source /Users/bezoadam/Documents/FIT/6.semester/BP/bp1/bin/activate; /usr/bin/env python3 /Users/bezoadam/Documents/FIT/6.semester/BP/facebook_down.py
```

Than I edited python files and pasted them into /BP_FINAL dir and used new crontab like this

```
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/bezoadam/Documents/FIT/6.semester/BP/BP_FINAL
0 * * * * source /Users/bezoadam/Documents/FIT/6.semester/BP/bp1/bin/activate; /usr/bin/env python3 /Users/bezoadam/Documents/FIT/6.semester/BP/BP_FINAL/twitter_down.py --hashtag
0 * * * * source /Users/bezoadam/Documents/FIT/6.semester/BP/bp1/bin/activate; /usr/bin/env python3 /Users/bezoadam/Documents/FIT/6.semester/BP/BP_FINAL/facebook_down.py
```

and now every run will throw an error from python file

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'new_emoji_sentiment.json'
```

When I run scripts in terminal everything works fine.
I think there is problem with `$PATH` but I don't know how to fix it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: One of your Python scripts obviously is trying to read a file with a hard- coded path. Update the filename in the affected script or move the required files to your new path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the current working directory from which the crontab runs your script is different than the folder from which your run your script manually. 
I suggest adding the absolute path of the files you're reading/writing to your script (maybe `/Users/bezoadam/Documents/FIT/6.semester/ ...`?) instead of a relative path (`new_emoji_sentiment.json`).

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. I added absoluthe path and everything works fine now. btw I don't know why I received negative point on my question. I followed all the question rules.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to add path one more time in your system file. And try to run this file in CMD prompt. It will run on that.

Comment: Why would that help? The OP has also said that it works from the terminal.(This is Un*x, so not CMD prompt)